# Alter Fieldable Panels Pane form

Tags: 7, panels, forms, distributions

Im using Panopoly, and have created a new Fieldable Panels Pane (FPP) bundle for a specific content type.

I notice that all preset Panopoly FPP's have a check box labelled 'Make title a link' inside a fieldset called 'General Options', which is also automatically added to my new bundle, and I can't for the life of me work out how to disable it!

For reference, this field is visible through the Panels IPE as well as the traditional /admin/structure/fieldable-panels-panes/manage/BUNDLE-NAME/add.

Does anyone know how I can isolate and disable this option on a per-bundle level?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost all Drupal forms can be edited using `hook_form_alter()`, specifying the form using its id:

Hide "Make title a link" for all fieldable panels panes:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 *
 * Simplify form for fpp.
 */
function your_module_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

  if ($form_id == 'fieldable_panels_panes_fieldable_panels_pane_content_type_edit_form') {
    $form['link']['#access'] = FALSE;
  }
}
```

Hide "Make title a link" for all fieldable panels panes of the type "your_bundle":

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 *
 * Simplify form for 'your_bundle' fpp.
 */
function your_module_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

  if ($form_id == 'fieldable_panels_panes_fieldable_panels_pane_content_type_edit_form') {
    if ($form['#bundle'] == 'your_bundle') {
      $form['link']['#access'] = FALSE;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a new sandbox [Simplify Extra](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/milkovsky/simplify_extra) which has integration with Fieldable Panels Panes.