# Fieldable panels panes - add a default category when creating

Tags: 7, panels

With Fieldable panels panes is it possible to programatically add a default category for all reusable entities?

Im adding new instances as follows, but it would be great if I could hard-code or even just suggest a category for all panes of this type to be created under. This way the Panels IPE wouldn't be such a mess if (when) editors don't set a category and everything gets lumped into 'Reusable Content'.

```
function logic_pane_bundles_entity_info_alter(&$entity_info) {

$entity_info['fieldable_panels_pane']['bundles']['poster_pane'] =
array(
    'label' => t('Poster Pane'),
    'pane category' => t('Hello bundles'),
    'pane top level' => TRUE, // set to true to make this show as a top level icon
    'pane icon' => '',
    'admin' => array(
        'path' => 'admin/structure/fieldable-panels-panes/manage/%fieldable_panels_panes_type',
        'bundle argument' => 4,
        // Note that this has all _ replaced with - from the bundle name.
        'real path' => 'admin/structure/fieldable-panels-panes/manage/poster-pane',
        'access arguments' => array('administer fieldable panels panes'),
    ),
);
```

}

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Currently it's not possible to assign a category in [hook_entity_info_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_entity_info_alter/7). See feature request https://www.drupal.org/node/2149989

To achieve this, couldn't you just fill the category form field, using [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) in a custom module, like in [my other answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/125771/alter-fieldable-panels-pane-form/128301#128301)?

Comment: Thanks for the idea Pere - I'll take a look at doing that